# Assembly: Limit the printing space for output and typing space for input

Tags: assembly, file-handling

I'm creating a program in which a user inputs a .txt file name and its contents, then the program can read and print the contents of that .txt file.

[This one is the part where the user will type the content and .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frn60.png)

[This one is the part where the program prints the contents of the .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvLeo.png)

variables:

```
    buff4 db 30
total4 db 0
char2 db 30 dup (0)

buff9 db 250
total9 db 0
text db 250 dup (0)
g db "Input text:$"

;view memo NEW
 a db "Filename:$"
  uMaxLength db 255
  uActualLength db ?
  szFileName db 255 dup (?)
  buffer db 100 dup (?), '$'
```

Creating the text file:

```
            crm proc near
            call cls
            call content
            call promptt
            call input2
            call file
            jmp open
            crm endp    

                  content proc near
                    mov ah, 2                       
                    mov dl, 16
                    mov dh, 8
                    int 10h

                    mov dx, offset buff9            ; buffered input
                    mov ah, 0ah
                    int 21h
                    mov bh, 0                       ; keyboard input
                    mov bl, total9                      
                    add bx, offset text
                    mov byte ptr [bx], 0
                    mov dx, offset text
                        cmp text, 'B'
                        je open
                        jne cmptexte
                    ret
                 content endp

                promptt    proc near
                 mov ah, 2                      
                 mov dl, 33
                 mov dh, 5
                 int 10h
                 ret
                promptt endp

              input2 proc near
               mov dx, offset buff4
               mov ah, 0ah
               int 21h
               mov bh, 0
               mov bl, total4
               add bx, offset char2
               mov byte ptr [bx], 0
               cmp char2, 'B'
               je open
               ret
              input2 endp

              file  proc near
               mov ah, 3ch
               mov cx, 0
               mov dx, offset char2
               int 21h
               mov h, ax                ;preserve
               mov ah, 40h          ;write
               mov bx, [h]
               mov cx, 250          ;string length
               mov dx, offset text
               int 21h
               mov ah, 3eh          ;close file
               mov bx, [h]
               int 21h
               ret
              file endp
```

Printing the text file:

```
            view proc near
         call cls


          mov ax, seg uMaxLength 
          mov ds, ax         

          mov ah, 0ah
          lea dx, uMaxLength ;read file name
          int 21h        

          mov ah, 2                     
          mov dl, 16
          mov dh, 8
          int 10h

          mov al, uActualLength 
          xor ah, ah
          mov si, ax
          mov szFileName[si], 0 ;make sz see 0A function

          cmp szFileName, 'B'
          je open
          jne cmpex

        view endp

                cmpex proc near
                    cmp szFileName, 'E'
                    je exit
                    jne view2
                cmpex endp

        view2 proc near
          mov ah, 3dh
          xor al, al 
          lea dx, szFileName
          int 21h ;open the file

          jc view ;if error

          mov bx, ax 

          repeat:
            mov ah, 3fh
            lea dx, buffer
            mov cx, 100 
            int 21h

            jc view; if error

            mov si, ax
            mov buffer[si], '$'

            mov ah, 09h
            int 21h ;print on screen

            cmp si, 100
            je repeat 

            call tdbe
            ret
        view2 endp

            cmpb proc near
                cmp openin, 'B'
                je menu
                jne cmpee
                ret
            cmpb endp

                    cmpee proc near
                        cmp openin, 'E'
                        je exit
                        jne open
                        ret
                    cmpee endp
```

What can I possibly do so that the text won't go out of the black text box? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looking at the pictures I understand what the problem is, but you need to show *the program code* that produced these results to get sensible help from me (and others).

Comment: If the content of file is being written to screen with `int 21h, ah=9` (if I read the code correctly), then you can't limit output of that service to particular rectangle of screen. Either use the other services to output character by character on particular coordinates, calculating layout of screen yourself, or even better, stop using the slow DOS/BIOS interrupts, and draw whole screen directly by overwriting video memory at `B800:0000` (still you have to calculate layout of screen any way, i.e. break too long lines, etc..). There's no simple solution, just compute it.